# Why does my progress bar disappear?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, progress-bar

I have seen this problem before but I haven't seen an answer to the question that applied to my particular case. I have a BackgroundWorker running in my VB form, as well as a progress bar and some labels. I also (if it's important) have a WebBrowser on my form, but it isn't affected by the thread.

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    Dim ints As Integer = Int(InputBox("What number to start at?"))
    Dim inte As Integer = Int(InputBox("What number to end at?"))
    ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "0 / " & inte - ints
    ToolStripProgressBar1.Maximum = inte
    ToolStripProgressBar1.Minimum = ints
    ToolStripProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous
    Try
        For z As Integer = ints To inte

            ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = z
            ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = z & "/" & inte
            'do some stuff here
    catch etc
    next
```

When the loop is running, sometimes it stops and the progress bar disappears. Any idea why?
Btw the only thing I'm doing in there is running an httpwebrequest and handling the string.

Comment: This code should bomb with an InvalidOperationException.  Whatever you did to bypass it, you'd better put it back.  It is quite illegal in Windows, painting artifacts is but the smaller problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely to do with the fact that you're setting the value of a user interface object (`ToolStripProgressBar1`) within the `BackgroundWorker`'s `DoWork` method which is running in it's own thread, separate from the User Interface thread which the `ToolStripProgressBar1` is in.

As per the Note on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx):

> You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in
>   your DoWork event handler. Instead, communicate to the user interface
>   through the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events.
>
> BackgroundWorker events are not marshaled across AppDomain boundaries.
>   Do not use a BackgroundWorker component to perform multithreaded
>   operations in more than one AppDomain.

What you should do is to change the code that's inside the loop (`For z As Integer = ints To inte`) so that instead of setting the `Value` and `Text` properties directly, you call the `BackgroundWorker`'s [`ReportProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx) method.  This raises the [`ProgressChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event which you can then handle on the main UI thread.  It's in here that you can then safely access the properties of User Interface components and objects.

Comment: I think I understand, however where would I put the "run worker completed" and is it important?
edit: Also, would it be better to use threading.thread?

Comment: Also, how do I send local vars to the events?

Comment: @BrianBTB - `Threading.Thread` is used "behind the scenes" by the `BackgroundWorker` class anyway.  You would still need to ensure that you don't interact with UI components from a non-UI thread either way.  The `RunWorkerCompleted` event **should** be handled no matter what you do as it act as a mechanism for you to handle any exceptions thrown from the `DoWork` code (which is running in a separate thread) as well as perform any clean-up required when the `DoWork` code completes or is cancelled.  The examples on the [MSDN Page](http://is.gd/maGmOc) should help.